# Python interpreter and script outputs different results

Tags: python

I have installed Python 2.7.12. I have tried to write some simple script and I got weird result so I run python interpreter and to my surprise I got different results. Here is my script:

```
import binascii
import bitarray

a = bitarray.bitarray(1)
a[0] = 0
print a
crc = binascii.crc_hqx(a, 0x0000)
print crc

b = bitarray.bitarray(1)
b[0] = 0
print b
crc = binascii.crc_hqx(b, 0x0000)
print crc
```

The output of above script is as follows:

```
bitarray('0')
0
bitarray('0')
33032
```

Value 33032 is wrong that is why I decided to check it using python interpreter and thats what I get:

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import binascii
>>> import bitarray
>>> a = bitarray.bitarray(1)
>>> a[0] = 0
>>> print a
bitarray('0')
>>> crc = binascii.crc_hqx(a, 0x0000)
>>> print crc
0
>>> b = bitarray.bitarray(1)
>>> b[0] = 0
>>> print b
bitarray('0')
>>> crc = binascii.crc_hqx(b, 0x0000)
>>> print crc
0
>>>
```

I sit in front of the desktop and struggle to find out what is wrong.

I use `bitarray` version 0.8.1.

Comment: Though I really doubt it could explain the error, do you run your code in the same Python version as the interpreter? In addition, you use the same name `crc` for both your crc's variables. Do you get the same output when naming them `crca` and `crcb`?

Comment: Can I print version inside script?

Comment: With naming `crca` and `crcb` the result is still wrong.

Comment: Add `help()` at the very beginning of your script.

Comment: This work with python 2.7.10. Have you tried to update your bitarray package with pip? It seems to be a bug with your bitarray package

Comment: `help()` prints out that I use Python 2.7. I have installed bitarray package with pip today.

Comment: It seems to be a bug of that module, as pointed by @MarcusRenno. Though I cannot give you a solution (besides the fact that I did not manage to install `bitarray`), I suggest that you edit your question to indicate what exact version of `bitarray` you are using, for further referencing of that problem. Besides, if you happened to find the solution by yourself, don't forget to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not solve the problem but I can say that I have omitted the problem. Instead of using `bitarray` I use `bitstring` package.